# Return multiple results in Web API based off value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have a WebForm that I'm working on. In the web form, I have several drop-downs that are dynamically populated:

```
Site
Store
Shelf
```

Previously, I used a `SQLConnection` type data string to populate the drop down fields, but I'm trying to convert them (and all my other `SQLConnection`s) to use an API.

The `Site` field is populated from my `SiteController.cs` API field. It is currently working correctly.

What I want to do with the `Store` field is have it pull from a separate controller, `ReviewController.cs`. I have the controller set up and working to pull data in general; however, I'm wondering if it's possible to have it return only the records where the `Site` attribute of the record is equal to the value from the `Site` drop-down on my form.

The idea that I'm working on is to add another method to my `ReviewController.cs` similar to the `GET` function for getting a single review, that would instead return all the reviews that have the `Site` field equal to a parameter. However, I'm not sure that that's possible, or how to do it. The reason I think it might not be possible is because I'm not sure the `ReviewController.cs` will have a place to put another `GET` call in its URL (it already has a `api/Review` and an `api/Review/{id}` method).

Here's the code that I'm working with so far:

```
    // GET: api/Review
    public IQueryable<Review> Get_Review()
    {
        return db.Review;
    }

    // GET: api
    public IEnumerable<Review> Get_store(string aa)
    {
        //This does not work
        return db.Review.Any(s => s.site == aa);
    }

    // GET: api/Review/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Review))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get_Review(int id)
    {
        Review review = db.Review.Find(id);
        if (Review == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(Review);
    }
```

Edit: I suppose that I should add that I'm CAPABLE of creating a separate API controller class to simply return the stuff that I need, but that seems like overkill to me in this case.

Comment: read up on attribute routing.

Comment: use a query param `/api/reviews?site={site}`

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for the tip! However, I'm not sure how to write the "return" statement of the API to get it to give what I want. Any tips on where to learn about that or what to search for?